# How to copy all files with extension/filetype in terminal?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, terminal, hard-drive

I want to copy all files in `~/Desktop` with the extension `.jpeg` to my flash drive.

How can I do this in the terminal?

Answer (score 17):

```
cp ~/Desktop/*.jpeg /Volumes/flashdrive/
```

will copy all of the files on the current user's desktop with extension ".jpeg" to the drive named "flashdrive".

If the above command produces an `Argument list too long` error, then the safest most efficient way to handle it is to use a `for` loop like this:

```
for f in ~/Desktop/*.jpeg; do cp "$f" /Volumes/flashdrive/; done
```

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
find /source/directory -iname \*.jpeg -exec cp {} /destination/directory/ \;
```

Where `/source/directory` is would be your `/Users/*username*/Desktop/` directory.

Answer provided from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336715/copy-files-across-directories-using-terminal-in-mac)

Comment: a simple `cp ~/Desktop/*.jpeg /flashdrive` is slightly less scary for a Terminal newbie...

Comment: This worked when the other answer gave me an "Argument list too long" error for ~60k files.